# Should we avoid using ID as CSS selector

Tags: html, css

I am talking about a whole new project, instead of legacy code, since I know sometime it takes so long duration and effort to refactor legacy code.

You may already know that the specificity of using ID as CSS selector is higher than using class name as CSS selector, so it is much more harder to override ID selector than class name selector.

```
<div class="class-a" id="id-a">Lorem Ipsum</div>

<style>
#id-a{
  color: blue;
}
.class-a{
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

E.g. For the code above, the text Lorem Ipsum will always in color blue instead of red even though the class name selector is being written after the id selector.

So why should someone use id as selector instead of using class name? Shouldn't we just use class name and maybe some time with tag name and totally avoid using id as CSS selector and leave id for javascript selector(Since it is much more efficient than using class name and tag name)?

If you would like to have a selector which is kind of unique to yourself and someone who are going to take up your code, you could actually do something like below.

```
<nav class="navigation-bar" id="navigation-bar">...</nav>
```

Use a same class name as the id of the element!

This is what I think, but I often see other developer using ID as CSS selector, why do so many people do that? Did I actually missed something? If yes, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because `id` is supposed to be unique, while classname can be reused many times.
Note that when using vanilla javascript / jQuery you will find that getting something out of ID is way more simple than classname.

Comment: My rule of thumb is, if there's already an id on an element, just use it. The idea of having an id is that there is only one element with it, so there's no need to add a class that is only going to be used once.

Comment: @mrLister I see what you mean, but my point is that if you use ID now, it could be harder for the person in the future to maintain the code especially if the CSS file contains many id. And there could be one day someone will even add !important to override the style instead of relocate the id selector and modify it.

Comment: @Saxon But maintainability problems exist the other way round too. What if person 1 adds a class to a unique element because they don't want to use an id for a selector, and person 2 later uses the same class somewhere else and then gets the same styles inadvertently. That wouldn't have happened if the id had been used to style it. Besides, you're exaggerating how hard it is to override styles for an id. You can just write the same `#idname` later in the stylesheet, or use a more specific selector like `body #idname` if necessary. Exactly the same as you can do with a `.classname`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic as it is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

`ID` is supposed to be unique but `CLASS` can be reused many times. Its better to use `CLASS` if you use frequently.